# How to create nested fields in Formik without object notation?

Tags: formik

Is there a way to created nested fields, for example (this doesn't actually work, but should get my point across):

```
<Field name="address">
    <GenericAddressFields />
</Field>
```

where `GenericFields` are just generic address fields such as `street`, `city`, etc, which may be re-used in many other forms. I know I could pass through a name prop which the rest of the form sub fields could use like `name={`${name}.street`}`, but that's messy, and assumes that the sub fields can be used that way.